# How to implement post video functionality like in Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement similar functionality like in facebook where you can post videos. So when you copy the link then facebook creates some sort of snapshot and then you post it.  I am searching around google how to do this but unfortunately didn't come across anything useful.

I want to know if there is something already implemented plugin or a tutorial to perform such action.

The only example I found is something like following used marked jQuery library. Is there something more elegant besides this.

```
marked.setOptions({
    gfm: true,
    pedantic: false,
    sanitize: true,
    highlight: null,
    urls: {
        youtube : function(text, url) {
            var cap;
            if((cap = /(youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(watch\?(.*&)?v=|(embed|v)\/))([^\?&"'>]+)/.exec(url))) {
                return '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + cap[5] + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe>';
            }
        },
        vimeo : function(text, url) {
            var cap;
            if((cap = /^.*(vimeo\.com\/)((channels\/[A-z]+\/)|(groups\/[A-z]+\/videos\/))?([0-9]+)/.exec(url))) {
                return '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + cap[5] +'" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
            }
        },
        dailymotion : function(text, url) {
            var cap;
            if((cap = /^.+dailymotion.com\/(video|hub)\/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=([^_&]+))?/.exec(url))) {
                return '<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="271" src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/' + cap[2] +'"></iframe>';
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse meta tags of the page. For example if you look the source code of youtube page you will find such tags, which are defined standards.

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB6a-iD6ZOY">
<meta property="og:title" content="Sting - Fragile">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lB6a-iD6ZOY/maxresdefault.jpg">

  <meta property="og:description" content="Music video by Sting performing Fragile. YouTube view counts pre-VEVO: 1,794,143. (C) 1991 A&amp;M Records">

<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="544007664">
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="YouTube">
  <meta property="al:ios:url" content="vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB6a-iD6ZOY&amp;feature=applinks">
<meta property="al:android:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB6a-iD6ZOY&amp;feature=applinks">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="YouTube">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.google.android.youtube">
<meta property="al:web:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB6a-iD6ZOY&amp;feature=applinks">

<meta property="og:type" content="video">
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/lB6a-iD6ZOY?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/lB6a-iD6ZOY?autohide=1&amp;version=3">
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="853">
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="480">

    <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Sting">
    <meta property="og:video:tag" content="A&amp;M">
    <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Rock">
```

You can seet that there is for example "og:image" meta tag, which basicaly points to the snapshot of the video. So this way you can get all the needed information. This is pretty much all you need to know to implement that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

i found this...http://embedly.github.io/jquery-preview/demo/

looks very elegant solution